# Permission-related installation error for Lets's Encrypt certbot snap

Tags: server, 18.04, snap, letsencrypt

I want to implement SSL on my Ubuntu 18.04 server which is using Nginx. I am following this link to implement it using Let's Encrypt: https://certbot.eff.org/

But after executing `sudo snap install --classic certbot` I get the following error:

```
error : cannot perform following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "certbot" snap if present 
  (run hook "configure": /var has 'other' write 40777)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -ld /var`?  Your directory permissions might be messed up.

Comment: Following is the output : drwxrwxrwx 14 root root 4096 Aug  5 07:30 /var

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment, it appears that snap is picky about your `/var` permissions.  It looks like those permissions were modified to be too open so you need to fix them by running the command `sudo chmod 0755 /var`.

Comment: thanks. It is working now. But why is it so?

Comment: `/var` normally has permissions 0755 so something changed it.  Is it possible you maybe ran a `chmod` on it at some point?

Comment: It is now asking for a domain name. Currently I just have IP address. What should I give in place of domain name??

Comment: Reading the Let's Encrypt docs, they will only issue a certificate for a domain, not an IP.